# Can I load my xbox games from a prior console onto a brand new console?

Tags: xbox-one

Clueless Dad question...   I bought an XBox One S for my daughter about 2 years ago.  It came preloaded w/ Minecraft bundle, and I also bought Lego Superheroes and Just Dance, which she had loaded on to it.  Recently, the XBox has stopped working, and Microsoft shrewdly charges just enough ($140) to repair it to make me consider buying a brand new console ($240).  The choice as to whether to repair or purchase new will depend on whether I am able to transfer those games to the new XBox One.  I'm not sure where the disc for Just Dance is (it might be inside the damaged XBox), and I seem to recall that the Lego Superheroes didn't come with a disc, just an install voucher??  Minecraft was preloaded so I don't think I have a disc for that either.

Will she be able to continue to play the games I've previously purchased if I buy a new console, without repurchasing them??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Minecraft was downloaded on the previous Xbox, signing into the same account on the Xbox One will allow you to download it on the Xbox One (or the newer version that came out for the One). Either way, yes, the download is free and should be able to play on the Xbox One